# count number of dates a single cell have

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have been trying to count the number of dates a single have and using below formula but its not working any help will be appreciated.

```
=LEN(FORMULATEXT(A5))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(A5)," ",""))+1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will split then count the number of columns in the split-out result:
It's using commas, spaces or carriage returns as the delimiters.

```
=IFERROR(COLUMNS(SPLIT(A5,", "&CHAR(10))),0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much can you please look at it attached sheet that why its not working @MattKing [Sheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wdpu7vPl3LwqqzK7Zs5XwPoVrviqMtafdSdt0E0mnCg/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I had a comma in the wrong place and will edit my answer.  should be fixed.